# Kotlin UByteArray and System.arraycopy

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I'm trying to copy array:

```
System.arraycopy(ret, 2, crcArray, 0, crcArray.size)
```

Both ret and crcArray are of type kotlin UByteArray.

Code is crashing with

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: source of type kotlin.UByteArray is not an array
```

Is there a way to copy ubytearrays using system method or I have to do it manually?

Comment: "kotlin UByteArray copy": https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/copy-into.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [UByteArray.copyInto(...)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/copy-into.html) for this:

```
val a = ubyteArrayOf(1u, 2u)
val b = UByteArray(2)

a.copyInto(b)
println(b)
```

```
UByteArray(storage=[1, 2])
```